# SharePoint 2013 Build versions are mismatching how to fix this issue?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

SharePoint 2013 Build versions are mismatching how to fix this issue?

QA and production version are different checked both versions in Central Administration both are available how to get it fixed.

Comment: Are you mean QA build number is different than the production Build number and you need to be identical?

Comment: check here https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/steve_chen/sharepoint-2013-build-numbers-and-cus/ your missing version number and apply patch/hotfix to the server.and make both identical.

Comment: Yes QA build number is different than the production Build numbe

Comment: @SanthoshKumar okay, please check my answer and my article to match both with one build number, and please don't hesitate to inform me if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the mention tips below:

- Get the current build number of the latest CU that has installed in your first farm. to get the latest CU in you farm check [FIND FARM PATCH LEVEL / LATEST CUMULATIVE UPDATE THAT HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON SHAREPOINT FARM](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)
- Get the corresponding components for your farm build number at [SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346)
- Repeat the above steps for the second farm.
- Check which farm has the highest build number.
- Download its corresponding component from [SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346)
- Install it on each server cross the farm that has the lower build number.
- Once the installation finished, Run configuration wizard on each server crosses the farm (preferred to start with the server that host the central admin).
- Now the two farm should have the same build number.

All details I wrote at [FIND FARM PATCH LEVEL / LATEST CUMULATIVE UPDATE THAT HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON SHAREPOINT FARM](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft all patch concept its mandate to run PSCONFIG to make effect of patch.

You have to run PSCONFIG and make sure it completed successfully then only your build version will come up.

This is the process to get build version of any patch or SP. If you want long explanation then I am sorry boss there is nothing  to explain much in this concept and I was working on this since 7.5 years and doing patch frequently and getting all build version.If you like then you may delete this post.

Thanks

Comment: You have mention to write why my answer is right then boss this is question and answer blog not discussion forum. Please use discussion forum for this.

Comment: I performed above steps not worked ..thanks for your help! also checked patches updates in qa and production looks same only still not getting updated.

Comment: Could you please provide the patch number and screenshot of build version after your patch. This will help me to dig more.